# Xamarin forms Resources designer.cs not creating using visual studio mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization, resx

[image]I'm facing a strange issue I have created a brand new xamarin forms project and i'm trying to adding **Resource file** in the shared project but when i add the Resource file then **.resx** extenshion file is created Like **AppResources.resx** creates but the code behind like **AppResource.designer.cs** not creating

**Things that i have tried.**

1. I have try multiple time and clean rebuild the project.
2. Create new project and try to again add resource file.
3. use custom tool to build the resource.

[image]

Comment: [Xamarin.Forms String and Image Localization, macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=macos) says "A .designer.cs class file can be created by setting a Custom Tool property in the resource file options". See that link for more details.

Comment: yes I have added and still face same issue @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: AppResources.resx Properties BuildAction = EmbeddedResource? If so, soundslike a bug in mac vs. Might have to use text editor to fix project’s .csproj file. See lines in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization.csproj

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes already  BuildAction =EmbeddedResources

Answer (score 1):

To manually fix the csproj, so it generates `AppResources.designer.cs` from `AppResources.resx`, follow these steps:

- Close Solution (or quit Visual Studio).
- Open YourProject.csproj in any text editor.
- Find all lines that refer to `AppResources.designer.cs` or `AppResources.resx`.
- Add or change as needed, to be similar to this (from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization.csproj):

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resx\AppResources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resx\AppResources.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

- Save the csproj file.
- Open your solution.